# Word for expressing when someone study alone

Tags: single-word-requests

When someone prefer to study alone, on his own, without school, I am tempted to use "self-student". But this word apparently doesnt exist.
Is there better way how to express this in one word?

**EDIT**

I wish to express that someone is good self-student. For example "Peter is a good self-student"

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you are thinking of an "autodidact: a self-taught person."

See: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/autodidact

Answer (score 0):

Definition of *self-study*:

> A way of ​learning about a ​subject that ​involves ​studying ​alone at ​home, ​rather than in a ​classroom with a ​teacher.

Example:

> The ​diploma is ​awarded ​following a ​course of *self-study* ​ending in a three-hour ​exam.

([Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/self-study))

Comment: Thank you, however i a need noun. When i am adressing someone, i want to say "He is a good self-student".